In Excel, when I select data for a graph, how to prevent arrow keys from selecting cells?
For any given graph, when a data range is specified, is there a way to type with arrow keys that does not result in a different cell being selected?
For example in the images below, I'd like to manually input $B$123:$B$1010, but whenever I use the keyboard cursors, it ends up adding unwanted cell references.
My current workarounds are as follows:

to use the mouse and avoid the arrow keys
select cells manually with the mouse
copy and edit the reference on a notepad app, then copy and paste it back into the data range

but any better alternative that also works from within Excel would be helpful.



While editing manually for Chart Data Ranges or if making changes manually in either Series for Legend entries or Horizontal axis, one needs to use the F2 Function Key.
Using the mouse or cursor adds unwanted cell references, therefore using the above-mentioned function key avoids that happening. This phenomenon is applied both in Data-Validation as well as when editing formulas in Conditional Formatting !

This bothered me since years, found the question only by chance via the sidebar of SO. Didn't know the F2-trick. Tried it out immediately and was surprised it works.

I cant believe I've never figured this out myself.  I use F2 all the time on cells to be able to move the text pointer with arrow keys.  It never occured to me to try it when editing a graph range, but it makes perfect sense and is pretty consistent with how it works in other places.

The mode that you're in is shown in the leftmost part of the bar at the bottom of excel.  F2 cycles through the possible modes.  Modes I've seen include Ready, Edit, Enter, Point.  Edit is the one where the arrows move the cursor, I think.
